# Why would you not use outut buffering in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers

To avoid the dreaded `Headers Already Sent` message we can turn on PHP’s output buffering:

```ini
#   PHP
    ini_sset('output_buffering', '1');
#   .user.ini
    output_buffering=On
#   .htaccess
    php_flag output_buffering On
```

The default value is `off`, so presumably it’s not always a good idea. I always try to write my PHP code so that it’s not necessarily.

However, what’s the disadvantage of turning output buffering on?

Comment: Do you understand _why_ you get this message? Then the question should mostly answer itself: your code is doing things in the wrong order and tries to output headers after already outputting body content. Trying to sweep this mistake under the rug with output buffering might be hiding the actual problems.

Comment: The question isn't about how to solve the `Headers Already Sent` issue though.. the question is about the **disadvantages of turning Output Buffering on**. The question doesn't answer itself. Sure, he's using Output Buffering to avoid the real issue, but the question about *what’s the disadvantage of turning output buffering on* is entirely valid and deserves an answer.

Comment: @deceze Yes, I understand _why_ I get this message. That’s why I always try to write my PHP code so that it’s not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output buffering is a mechanism in PHP that controls how output data (HTML, XML, JSON, etc.) from your scripts is sent to the client's browser. When output buffering is enabled, PHP will store the output data in a temporary buffer (think of it like a cache) instead of immediately sending it to the client. This buffer can be flushed manually or automatically, depending on your specific requirements.

This gives you the flexibility to capture and manipulate your scripts' output *before* sending it to the client, **so you can do thinks like set headers after you've `echo`'d or outputted content in your script, which you normally can't do.**

Output buffering can be useful for mitigating issues like "Headers Already Sent" (normally, headers must be sent before any actual output is sent), but it definitely come with trade-offs:

### Memory Consumption

When you enable output buffering, you're instructing PHP to store the HTML output in memory until it's ready to be sent. For big pages with lots of content, this could lead to increased memory usage, potentially affecting the performance of your server or even leading to out-of-memory errors.

### Delayed Output

Due to how PHP manages output buffering, the client's browser won't actually start receiving data until PHP has fully processed the script, or until you explicitly flush the buffer. This could lead to a perception of slower page loads for end-users, especially for content-heavy pages.

### Error Diagnosis

Because the output is buffered, run-time errors (PHP errors/notices) aren't displayed immediately. This can make debugging more difficult as error messages won't appear in the place where they are triggered.

### Inefficient for Streaming

If you are working with real-time applications or streaming content, output buffering can be counter-productive because you would ideally want data to be sent to the client as soon as it is available.

### Code Quality

Relying on output buffering to solve "Headers Already Sent" issues (depending on what's causing the issue) could be seen as a work-around, or a ["hack job"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hack%20job). If you're using output buffering to solve this problem, the better practice would be to structure your PHP code so that all headers are sent before any output, making the application more maintainable and easier to understand.

### Example Usage

Here's a simple example demonstrating the benefits of output buffering:

```php
// Without Output Buffering
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo "Hello, World!";

// Output buffering allows us to change headers even after sending output
ob_start();
echo "Hello, World!";
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); // This would not work without output buffering
ob_end_flush(); // Flush buffer, send output to browser
```

Comment: Wonder where did you get that " won't appear in the place where they are triggered" stuff

Comment: I think it's just a wording issue. Errors that would normally get reported at once, will be delayed to a later step in code workflow, or even masked altogether.